# How do I set a class for the <ul> of a TypedChoiceField?

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm rendering a `TypedChoiceField`, with a `RadioSelect` widget. Setting `attrs={'class':'radio'}` for the widget, this class is applied to the `<input>`, but this input is nested in a `<ul>`. I would like to set a class for this `<ul>`, where should I do so?

I am currently still on Django 1.3, so a `RadioSelect` isn't an option.

From my Form:

```
yesno = forms.TypedChoiceField(
               coerce=lambda x: True if x == 'Yes' else False,
               choices=((False, 'No'), (True, 'Yes')),
               widget=forms.RadioSelect)
```

The actual HTML:

```
<ul>
<li>
  <label for="yesno_0">
    <input value="False" type="radio" name="yesno" id="yesno_0"> 
    No
  </label>
</li>
<li>
  <label for="yesno_1">
    <input name="yesno" value="True" id="yesno_1" type="radio"> 
    Yes
  </label>
</li>
</ul>
```

What I'd like:

```
<ul class='myclass'>
<li>
  <label for="yesno_0">
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way i see:
You could create a custom RadioSelect widget, inherited from the widgets.RadioSelect and override the "renderer" property and set it to your custom RadioFieldRenderer (also inherited from widgets.RadioFieldRenderer) and override the "render" method

```
class CustomRadioFieldRenderer(widgets.RadioFieldRenderer):
    def render(self):
        return mark_safe(u'<ul class="YOUR-CLASS-HERE">\n%s\n</ul>' % u'\n'.join([u'<li>%s</li>'
            % force_unicode(w) for w in self]))


class CustomRadioSelect(widgets.RadioSelect):
    renderer = CustomRadioFieldRenderer


yesno = forms.TypedChoiceField(widget=CustomRadioSelect, *args, **kwargs)
```

Or call `render` with a `super()` and then replace `<ul>` with a `<ul class=''>`, that's a detail

Comment: That's you choice, you could either put it near your form class or define a module widgets.py in your app folder (i do this sometimes)